# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::fireCustomModelEvent()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a project that was created by someone else using Laravel 5.2. I thought I should update this project to at least Laravel 5.3 using the [Laravel Guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade). When I serve my application it runs correctly but when I try to authenticate myself it gives the error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::fireCustomModelEvent()

When I discard the changes in the composer.lock file the run composer install, it's fine (obviously does not recognise the Laravel 5.3 changes). This happens when I run composer install.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching your entire project directory for references to fireCustomModelEvent.  My suspicion is that you have a library listed in your composer.json file that should have been updated and didn't get updated as part of your migration.

If you have any listings in your vendor folder that turn up results, you will need to update the corresponding package in your composer.json file.

Comment: I did search for it, I can't find it anywhere. I updated everything. In fact, it is after I update the packages that I get this error.

Comment: What does the full stack trace give you?